# Unable to read a JSON file in my simple python code

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I get the below error when i try to read a JSON file, not sure what needs to be corrected:

```
C:\Users\prabhjot2600\PycharmProjects\PythonPractise\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/prabhjot2600/Desktop/Prabh/alien_invasion/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/prabhjot2600/Desktop/Prabh/alien_invasion/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = json.loads(people_string)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 11 column 21 (char 192)
```

My code is simply reading a JSON file and printing its data. I have checked my JSON data also which looks correct and also formatted it to see if there were any errors left but still cant read the JSON

```
import json

people_string = '''
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Prabhjot Singh",
      "phone": "9999596310",
      "emails": [
        "prabh@noemail.com",
        "prabhjot@ranamail.com"
      ],
      "hasLicence": True
    },
    {
      "name": "Sunny Rana",
      "phone": "9999988888",
      "emails": null,
      "hasLicence": False
    }
  ]
}
'''


data = json.loads(people_string)
print(data)
```

Comment: JSON uses `true` and `false` instead of `True` and `False`.

Answer (score 1):

JSON stands for **JavaScript Object Notation**.
So it is subset of Javascript's syntax.
Javascript uses `true` and `false` keyword as literal boolean values.
(Whereas python uses `True` and `False`).

Therefore, you should use `true` and `false` instead of `True` and `False`.
See https://www.json.org/json-en.html for detailed syntax.